# Web API: 500 error after short timeout

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I've got my Web API interface working fine but after a fairly short period, like around 5 minutes, it gives a 500 Internal Server Error on the first call and then works fine again until it times out. I'm not getting any additional information on the error message and there's nothing going to the logs. I don't have the issue on my development machine, just on the live server. Any ideas what might be causing this? How can I get additional error information on a live server?

Comment: Turn on failed request tracing. http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: 500 is just a generic Server error. As mentioned before use Regiestil tracing to get more informations

Comment: I turned on Failed Request Tracing and it generated a file. But the file is 5000 lines long for a single request and I'm not seeing any obvious errors by scanning through it. Is there something I should be looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to this was set Custom Errors Off within the Web.config file. That gave a very useful error that made it easy to track down the problem.